# Paypal API MassPay for 1 user

Tags: api, paypal, payment, masspay

Any problem in use MassPay to pay 1 user payment? Any disavantage about that? What should i use instead mass pay for single payments?

I see that paypal forum is dead so im aking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassPay is fine. If you're already using Adaptive Payments, you could also use Implicit Payments. But if you're not, MassPay suits just fine.

Comment: Thanks thats all i need to know :)

Answer (score 0):

MassPay works fine with single or multiple payments.  It makes payment more flexible.

Comment: Thanks thats all i need to know :)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms Masspay allows you to make multiple payments to multiple people in a single shot using xls or csv files.

If you are just paying a single user:

PayPal provides various payment related operations using the /payment resource and related sub-resources. Use /payment for direct credit card payments and PayPal account payments.

URI: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Create a payment: POST /v1/payments/payment

For more information, refer:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment